# Why do i need to provide a redirect url for a spotify android app?

Tags: android, flutter, spotify

Hello intelligent people,

may anyone explain to me why i need to set a redirect url in the spotify app settings when i am developing an android app. I dont need the application to route me to another website, since there is none.
Do i missunderstand the purpose of the redirect url?
Which url should i use? According to the tutorial provided by spotify i need provide one, but i cant understand why.
I am aware that this question for sure has been answered in the past, but i can´t seem to find any previous thread that targets this particular question.

Thank for your help.

Comment: its mostly done for authorization purpose

Comment: Sounds like they're doing OAuth.  I'd be reading up on how OAuth works, its a fairly complicated system.  You may not be using the right API for a mobile app, it sounds like the API you're using expects it to be a website.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am unsing the Spotify Android Sdk which, in theory take care of the authorization process. In addition to that i am using an adapter package to make it usable in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

> In Redirect URIs enter one or more addresses that you want to allowlist with Spotify. This URI enables the Spotify authentication service to automatically invoke your app every time the user logs in (e.g. http://localhost:8080)

See [App Settings](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/app-settings/) for details. See [Authorization Code Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/)
 how it is used.